# Data handling in R; Data tables

Tags: r

Is there any alternative solution for the question?

1. Create a Data Table using the R built-in dataset `mtcars`
2. Find the average-weight(`wt`) & average horse-power(`hp`) of all cars with a mileage above 15 mpg, grouped by number of cylinders(`cyl`) and carburettors(`carb`).

```
    s<-data.table(mtcars)
    s[mpg>15,.(mean(wt),mean(hp)),by=.(cyl,carb)]
```

Comment: You can do the same in base R or `dplyr` but what is the problem with current solution ?

Answer (score 1):

#If is for Fresco you need to add the library

```
library(data.table)
s<-data.table(mtcars)
  s[mpg>15,.(mean(wt),mean(hp)),by=.(cyl,carb)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dpylr` solution would be:

```
require(dplyr)
as_data_frame(mtcars) %>% 
  filter(mpg > 15) %>% 
  group_by(cyl, carb) %>%
  summarise(mean_wt = mean(wt),
            mean_hb = mean(hp))
```